# decoding Groupme API 'created_at' object?

Tags: javascript, api, groupme

I'm messing with CURL and GroupMe's API. I'm trying to figure out when a certain chat was created and I'm getting a 'created_at' object that has a string of numbers:

`1434766147`

Not exactly sure how to read it. There's no documentation on it. Any help would be appreciated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a timestamp in [unix time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You should do this `const createdAt = new Date(1434766147 * 1000)` to get an actual JavaScript date object